# Is there a word for a person playfully pretending to believe an equally playful obvious lie?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Imagine I tell someone "you know, my music playing is so advanced, but so advanced, that I play the piano with my two hands on my back!" — and the person nods with feigned belief as if agreeing that is an amazing skill and there's nothing strange about my assertion.

Now, I can tell people can make that kind of expression without saying a word, even if the idea is less outrageous, and we know it's in a playful way. Or perhaps I tell the person an authentic, albeit not too dramatic, lie, and they act this way in a slightly sarcastic manner, as if saying "yes, of course you do, I completely believe you."

Well, I'm trying to find the word, or term, to describe this action. If there is any.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is the idiom ***go along with the gag***

> (idiomatic) To cooperate in continuing a joke, hoax, or similar phenomenon initiated by others. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_along_with_the_gag))

[FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+along+with+the+gag) defines it as

> To follow along with someone or something in ***prolonging a joke***.

In your context it is clear that this is a joke, so I think the phrase ***[play along](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/play-along)*** is also appropriate.